# How can I pluck a string of a guitar with a constant force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, home-experiment, experimental-technique

I'm trying to perform an experiment but need ideas on how to pluck a string with a constant force using household objects/equipment.

Comment: so you basically want an instrument that can directly/indirectly measure force?

Comment: An instrument that can produce a consistent force. Doesn't have to be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to my mind is to use a pen-pencil spring. Pull the string with the spring, the extension of the spring will give pretty good estimate of force and the extension can be measured by ordinary mm precision scale.

Answer (score 0):

What about the sort of $G$ -shaped mechanism sketched below

[image: Phys_guitar_pull_1]

A tiny band of elastic steel with a rounded tip, which upholds the cord till the force is such as to open the gap.
The elastic band might be fixed to the chassis through a regulable slide which varies the length of the band that can bend.

Comment: A chord is not a cord

Comment: @electronpusher: oops, I was "tuned" on maths : thanks for signalling

Comment: @GCab, could you tell me what application you used to create that drawing?

Comment: @Pinkproton: just drawn on excel

Answer (score 0):

**Magnets**

Permanent magnets attract one another with a (mostly) fixed amount of force, so the force required to separate two magnets is constant. Attach one magnet to the string, and allow the other magnet to attract freely. Now pull the second magnet directly upward - the magnets will release when the force pulling the string exceeds the force holding the magnets together.

A few caveats are that this requires that you have a magnet attached to your string, which you may not want. Magnet behavior can also depend somewhat on temperature, so it'll be best to keep your experimental apparatus in a controlled environment. Finally, this apparatus will release at a fairly consistent amount of force, but won't tell you what that amount of force is.

You could do something similar with any item that has some constant breaking strength, like fishing line for example. Just pull until the item breaks and releases the string, which should occur at a fairly constant level of force.